# iPython - library function help in debug mode

Tags: python, matlab, function, debugging, ipython

I was wondering how to access the help page of library functions when I'm in the debug mode in iPython. For instance,

```
ipdb> help(numpy.random.randn)
```

does not work in debug mode, as it is not an ipdb command.

I can do something like this in Matlab, where

```
K>> help(randn)
```

returns the help page of randn even though I'm in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!help(numpy.random.randn)` instead in pdb.

The `!` exclamation mark ensures that pdb does not try to execute the line as a pdb command, passing it to the Python interpreter instead.

Comment: I noticed that this also works for variable names that conflict with ipdb help commands. Thanks!

Comment: @user1953384: exactly. `!list(generator_function())` is my favourite use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ipython installed but most probably you can access the help with

```
print randn.__doc__
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been long since I used iPython, but I think you should be able to do this:

```
ipdb> import numpy
ipdb> import pydoc
ipdb> pydoc.help(numpy.random.randn)
```